# MySQL Run Stored Procedure Asynchronously

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We have a requirement to run an update to potentially thousands of objects every few minutes. Each of the updates using a stored procedure take about four tenths of a second so running thousands of these sequentially takes approx 6.5 mins per 1000 runs.
We will be using MySQL Events to run the process every 5 mins.

The store procedure runs on a subset of rows in a table calculating various dates on that subset of rows. Each fetch is only getting the next master record to work on the subset of rows.

The event will look something like this

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE CURSOR....

    OPEN CURSOR and FETCH....

    FOR EACH FETCH
        CALL Stored_Procedure(Parameters from Fetch) # This is what we want to call asynchronously

    CLOSE CURSOR
END
```

This runs ok synchronously but takes too long when we scale.

I would be grateful for any ideas please.

Comment: Can you refactor the stored procedure to handle multiple rows in one go rather than having to be invoked row-by-row with FETCH results? Please [edit] your question to tell us more.

Comment: Divide to some parts by some expression, execute separate SP copy for each part by separate event.

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature to use `CALL` or any other SQL statement asynchronously. In a given session, MySQL executes only one thread. So you must use multiple sessions if you want to run this in parallel.

There is no way to create a new session in a stored procedure. You have to do this in client code.

Don't try to use a single MySQL connection over multiple threads in your client. MySQL is a stateful protocol, and you'll cause the protocol to get mixed up if you try to send messages from multiple threads. You must open a separate MySQL connection in each thread of your client.

I've written code like this in Go. Go makes it pretty easy to create a pool of threads to consume a list of items to work on. But you don't mention which client language you are using.

Another strategy would be to optimize the updates so they don't take so long per batch. But you don't show the updates themselves, only your hypothetical stored procedure.